# VHDL Case statement adds significant overhead

Tags: vhdl

Here is the code snippet:

```
WITH MUX SELECT
S <= ((h_sum(N-1 DOWNTO 1) XOR carry_in_internal(N-1 DOWNTO 1)) & (h_sum(0) XOR C_in_mod)) WHEN "0010" | "0110",
    carry_generate WHEN "0000",
    carry_propagate WHEN "0001",
    h_sum WHEN "0100",
    nor_val WHEN "1100",
    A WHEN OTHERS;
```

The delay timing was almost 17ns. When commenting out a set of statements:

```
WITH MUX SELECT
S <= ((h_sum(N-1 DOWNTO 1) XOR carry_in_internal(N-1 DOWNTO 1)) & (h_sum(0) XOR C_in_mod)) WHEN "0010" | "0110",
    --carry_generate WHEN "0000",
    --carry_propagate WHEN "0001",
    --h_sum WHEN "0100",
    --nor_val WHEN "1100",
    A WHEN OTHERS;
```

The delay timing became 11ns! How come this is the case? How does having additional switches add so much gate overhead, I am unable to comprehend. Is there an easier way? essentially, i assume the FPGA has the output to S from a flip-flop or memory block. Hence, all it needs to do is decide which 32bit flip/flop to read from yes?

Comment: Not sure, but this might be a slightly better question for [EE.SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @raaj: When considering physical properties like delay it depends heavily on the FPGA device and its architecture, and is not purely a VHDL question, so you should add information about FPGA device, and update the tags accordingly.  Also, what delay do you refer to?  If the critical is through one of the parts commented out it is easy to understand whey the delay changes significantly.

Comment: There is no '32bit flip/flop' or 'memory block' evident in your code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in the second case you have to recognize only one combination of inputs and then you have basically 32 2to1 Mux and a little logic to address the the selectors, in the first case you have 8to1 MUX and much more logic for the selector. (It is just give you an idea of why you have such area overhead, but how your code is mapped depends on your FPGA and on the tool you are using).

Unfortunately I don't think there is a better way to write your MUX.

What you could do is to try to change the codification of MUX in order to reduce the number of bit to recognize or try to split the MUX in more than one stage and see if it speed up your system.

Bye

Comment: To improve timing performance, make sure that you clock everything that you can - if `MUX` is a combinational output, its delay will compound with the multiplexing logic. You might also look at immediately registering the combinational output `S` before using it as an input to any other logic. The most surefire way to fix it is to pipeline (split the multiplexer into more than one stage) and accept some delay (but no reduced througput); this is very easy with feed-forward logic but can be a headache when you have feedback.